# how to start an opc ua client for embedded STM32 board

Tags: embedded, opc, stm32f4discovery, opc-ua

Recently, I need some idea about how to start an OPC UA client programm on an embedded STM32, I do how to use the ansi C stack provided by OPC foundation

Comment: Can this toolchain target the STM32?

Comment: http://www.matrikonopc.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Embedded UA Server Toolkit from MatrikonOPC is cross platform and can target the STM32.  It's actually one of the boards used for development.